# I have KeySignature Error How To Solve This?

Tags: android, jks, google-console-developer

[image]

I have published my app in Google Console and I contact google developer help desk and I upload new jks on google console, I try generate with new jks and I have this error 
How To Resolve This?

I tried different alias name but I couldn't solve  may be I forgot alias name but I am sure its name key0 ..

```
Something went wrong with the encryption tool

java.lang.NullPointerException: No key for alias: key0
    at com.google.wireless.android.vending.developer.signing.tools.extern.export.Utils.checkNotNull(Utils.java:55)
    at com.google.wireless.android.vending.developer.signing.tools.extern.export.KeystoreHelper.extractPrivateKey(KeystoreHelper.java:56)
    at com.google.wireless.android.vending.developer.signing.tools.extern.export.KeystoreHelper.getPrivateKey(KeystoreHelper.java:35)
    at com.google.wireless.android.vending.developer.signing.tools.extern.export.ExportEncryptedPrivateKeyTool.run(ExportEncryptedPrivateKeyTool.java:98)
    at org.jetbrains.android.exportSignedPackage.ExportSignedPackageWizard$2.run(ExportSignedPackageWizard.java:232)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$TaskRunnable.run(CoreProgressManager.java:736)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.lambda$runProcess$1(CoreProgressManager.java:157)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.registerIndicatorAndRun(CoreProgressManager.java:580)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(CoreProgressManager.java:525)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:85)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.runProcess(CoreProgressManager.java:144)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$4.run(CoreProgressManager.java:395)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$1.run(ApplicationImpl.java:314)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can list all certificates in the keystore like

on Linux

`keytool -list -v -keystore keystore.jks | grep "Alias name\|Creation date"`

on Windows

`keytool -list -v -keystore keystore.jks | findstr "Alias Creation"`

Answer (score 0):

Get some binary editor and see your private key file with it. You may find the alias.

NB. Capital letters are converted to lower case in that file.